# Find date difference based on condition

Tags: spotfire, tibco

I have a table where data may be provided on monthly or yearly basis. The table data looks something as below:

```
Item        Date        Name
Class 1     12/31/2010  David
Class 1     12/31/2011  David
Class 1     12/31/2012  David
Class 1     12/31/2010  Moses
Class 1     12/31/2011  Moses
Class 1     12/31/2012  Moses
Class 1     01/31/2012  Shelly
Class 1     02/28/2012  Shelly
Class 1     03/31/2012  Shelly
Class 1     04/30/2012  Shelly
Class 1     05/31/2012  Shelly
Class 1     06/30/2012  Shelly
Class 1     07/31/2012  Shelly
Class 1     08/31/2012  Shelly
Class 1     09/30/2012  Shelly
Class 1     10/31/2012  Shelly
Class 1     11/30/2012  Shelly
Class 1     12/31/2012  Shelly

Class 2     01/31/2012  Shelly
Class 2     02/28/2012  Shelly
Class 2     03/31/2012  Shelly
Class 2     04/30/2012  Shelly
Class 2     05/31/2012  Shelly
Class 2     06/30/2012  Shelly
Class 2     07/31/2012  Shelly
Class 2     08/31/2012  Shelly
Class 2     09/30/2012  Shelly
Class 2     10/31/2012  Shelly
Class 2     11/30/2012  Shelly
Class 2     12/31/2012  Shelly
Class 2     01/31/2012  David
Class 2     02/28/2012  David
Class 2     03/31/2012  David
Class 2     04/30/2012  David
Class 2     05/31/2012  David
Class 2     12/31/2011  Soni
Class 2     12/31/2012  Soni
```

For a combination of `Name and Item`, either the date difference can be `monthly` or `yearly`. I want to include a calculated column named `Flag`. The condition to set flag is, if users had entered `monthly` data then set value as `Yes` else No.

So the rows with Class 1 - Shelly and all rows of Class 2 excluding Soni should be set as Yes.

Can anyone please guide me on this ? If I try Over and Intersect, for some of the columns, result is blank row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have at least 2 months of data for each Item / Name pairing, you can approach this two ways. Note, that unless you have 2 months of data you can't tell if, for the given year, you are receiving data monthly or yearly.

1. Insert Calculated Column `DatePart("year",[Date]) as [Year]`
2. Insert Calculated Column `If(Count([Item]) OVER (Intersect([Name],[Item],[Year]))>1,"Yes","No") as [Flag]`

Another expression that you *may* find useful will apply a rank / row number to each `Year | Month | Item | Name` pairing. Here is that expression which you can use to see how many months of data you have for that paring (using `MAX()`) or to do other aggregates / logical checks.

```
RankReal(Date(DatePart("year",[Date]),DatePart("month",[Date]),1),"asc",[Name],[Item],DatePart("year",[Date]),"ties.method=minimum") as [RowRank]
```

Comment: This is bingo !! Thank you so much. So it would work only if we have more than one rows for monthly data ?

Comment: Correct... because logically if you only had one row there is no way to determine if the data is coming monthly. For example, if I am a new name starting this month, you would have Class1, scsimon, 3/21/2017. With this data, you don't (yet) know if you will get data for me next month. If you do get a record for me next month the flag will be YES on all rows. Otherwise, it will remain NO. The only other thing you can do is default it to YES, but i feel like this assumption is worse than the current default of NO.